# Missing tables from MySQL restore

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, restore

I'm not a DBA  but a JIRA admin. I run a cron backup of my mysql InnoDB JIRA database which runs a script that executes the command below:

```
mysqldump -v --single-transaction --user=DATABASEUSER --password=PASSWORD? --max_allowed_packet=1024M DATABASE > /backup/mysql/DATABASE_$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M).sql 2> /backup/log/DATABASE_backup_$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M).log
```

The application is running during the backup. If I try to restore this backup file, I find that not all the tables are backed up and a load of them is missing. Only 130 out of 430 tables are being restored.

The restore was done by first creating the database and then specifying the source of the SQL dump:

CREATE DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
Use databasename;
Source /pathtofile

Any ideas why tables will be missing from such a backup command?

We have 5.6.36 version of MySQL

Cheers,

Comment: Another SE may be a better fit for this question. I help run our JIRA and it is a beast on its own. Unfortunately, I didn't find its own site. But the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira has over 3,500 questions if you cant find an answer here.